# Is solution file necessary to open and the run a website project in Visual Studio 2008 - 2017?

Tags: asp.net, web

I am able to open and run a website project in VS without having solution file. Is solution file necessary to open and the run a website project in Visual Studio 2008 - 2017? If is it need, what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory.

The main purpose of a VS solution is to provide a container for a collection of multiple projects and propagate source control configuration information down to contained projects.

Last but not least it allows to run a build of its projects and organize dependencies between projects.